# What happens when running this code?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running this piece of code:

```
$sql = "SELECT IF(TIMEDIFF(NOW(),last_update) > '02:00:00',1,0) AS morethan FROM products LIMIT 1";

    if($stmt = $this->connect->prepare($sql)) {
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($result);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    return $result;
```

I get `0`, that means that the difference I'm checking for it wasn't found ?

Comment: lot of code is missing i think... what is $result?

Comment: Yes, I get 0. I'm trying to get the difference between times or some kind of false or true if the difference is more than 2Hours.

Comment: @toPeerOrNotToPeer - `$result` is the var I'm binding the result I get to, but I'm not sure what happens there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysql IF works like this:

```
IF(condition, true, false)
```

That you revceive 0 in the result "morethan " it means that

```
TIMEDIFF(NOW(),last_update) > '02:00:00'
```

is false, in other words the timediff is smaller than 02:00:00

Comment: That's what I wanted to hear, so it is ok to do it like that ? I can even remove that `AS` ?

Comment: there are several ways to do it, your's is one of them ;) yes the AS is not required.

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite your query just removing the `IF`:

```
SELECT (TIMEDIFF(NOW(),last_update) > '02:00:00') morethan FROM products LIMIT 1
```

Your query will actually non-deterministically get a row (this means you can't predict which row) from the table products and check if it matches your condition. If it does, the query will return `1`, otherwise `0`. I think that is not your intention, right?

If you want to check if there is any row that fulfills that condition you can do this:

```
select 1 existsInTable from products
where TIMEDIFF(NOW(),last_update) > '02:00:00'
limit 1
```

This will return `1` whenever a match is found and an empty resultset when no match is found. You don't even need to check the values returned as you can just count the numbers of intems returned by the query with [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php).

Comment: +1 I don't want to rewrite it, it already works like I had it before, I needed a confirmation that it actually does what I thought it does :) And thank you for the tip, I'll try your method to see the result.

Comment: @Roland Be careful. In the answer I'm telling you that your query is not doing what you want :) To make it clearer: It will take a *random* row and check if it fulfills the condition and return `1` or `0`. It is almost like flipping a coin.

Comment: But that's the thing, that value I'm checking for it's the same in all the rows, so if in any of the rows a dif more than 2hr is encountered than I need to update all the info.

Comment: Oh ok! That's a weird requirement. Then if you are sure that all rows have the same value then don't use my second query because it will check if there is *any* row fulfilling that criteria